# Как передать значение select в php ?

Tags: php

Нужно передать значение value в php

```
<select>
  <option value="1">Цифра 1</option>
  <option value="2">Цифра 2</option>
</select>

<?php

........

?>
```

Comment: Тоже учу PHP... И не вижу чтоб мануалов было дофига. От текстового поля передаёт значения от "выборщика" <select> - никак не получается. Гуглю уже который день по разным ключам! Сгенерировал в теге цикл от 1 до 1000...

Comment: От выборщика "селект"! Тут не отобразился тег...

Answer (score 8):

Как вариант

```
<select name="select"> 
        <option value="-1">Причина обращения </option>
        <option value="Вариант 1">Вариант 1</option> 
        <option value="Вариант 2">Вариант 2 </option>
        <option value="Вариант 3">Вариант 3 </option>
    </select>
```

соответственно обработчик, чтобы передать name

```
<?php

$select = htmlspecialchars ($_POST["select"]);

$myemail = "you@mail.ru";

$to = "you@mail.ru"; 
$subject = "Сообщение от посетителя сайта";
$message = "\nПричина обращения:$select"; 
mail ($to,$subject,$message, "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 \r\n") or print "Не могу отправить сообщение.";
?>
```

Comment: Блин, не успел. Но это точное решение, только добавь объявление метода передачи данных в форме.

Comment: я думаю это не проблема method="get/post"

Answer (score 0):

Вообще нельзя просто взять и передать. Вы похоже не очень хорошо понимаете принцип работы.

Браузер запрашивает страницу -> выполняется php код -> браузеру отдается сгенерированная страница.

Вы не можете "передать" селект в php потому что php код уже давно выполнился.

Вам надо сделать форму отправляющую данные на php скрипт, и там уже обработать. мануалов по этому вопросу чуть больше чем дофига, гуглите

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
    <select name="select"> 
        <option value="-1">Причина обращения </option>
        <option value="Вариант 1">Вариант 1</option> 
        <option value="Вариант 2">Вариант 2 </option>
        <option value="Вариант 3">Вариант 3 </option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Такой ответ, только более полный, уже был дан на этот вопрос. То, что Вы делаете - это  называется плагиат.